# How to use Vue components with separated files? (TS/HTML/SCSS)

Tags: vuejs2

I installed the `Vue` sample with `Vue CLI 3` (with Typescript and Scss) and I changed the `HelloWorld.vue` to these separated files:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But it does not work.
I got this error in `build`.

```
These dependencies were not found:

* HelloWorld.html?vue&type=template&id=5a1e3016&scoped=true&lang=html& in ./src/
components/HelloWorld.vue
* HelloWorld.scss?vue&type=style&index=0&id=5a1e3016&lang=scss&scoped=true& in .
/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

To install them, you can run: npm install --save HelloWorld.html?vue&type=templa
te&id=5a1e3016&scoped=true&lang=html& HelloWorld.scss?vue&type=style&index=0&id=
5a1e3016&lang=scss&scoped=true&
```

`Ivan You` said in [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify/issues/35#issuecomment-161436380) this should be possible but does not work for me How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add to your source `"./..."`, i.e.

```
src="./HelloWorld.html"

src="./HelloWorld.scss"
```